# Redmine working on localhost but not accessible from the web?

Tags: apache, localhost, redmine

I have recently installed Redmine on my Ubuntu 11.10 box here at work,
and have it working fine from localhost/redmine. Now I am trying to put
it out on the web for others in my office to use but am running into a
hitch somewhere. I read through multiple threads but have not found an
answer. The latest thing was appending

> Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"

I've tried accessing it via my http://2222.us/redmine but only receive
connection timeout errors. The contents of my httpd.conf is just one line

> ServerName 127.0.0.1

Port 80 IS listening

> # netstat -nao | grep 80
>
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

And the contents of my sites-enabled file for Redmine is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jd@neongecko.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    # See 
    # http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html 
    # for details on what these options do.  They will lead to an increase
    # in memory usage, but significantly reduced access times.


    # Speeds up spawn time tremendously -- if your app is compatible. 
    # RMagick seems to be incompatible with smart spawning
    PassengerSpawnMethod smart


    # Keep the application instances alive longer. Default is 300 (seconds)
    PassengerPoolIdleTime 300


    # Additionally keep a copy of the Rails framework in memory. If you're 
    # using multiple apps on the same version of Rails, this will speed up
    # the creation of new RailsAppSpawners. This isn't necessary if you're
    # only running one or 2 applications, or if your applications use
    # different versions of Rails.
    RailsFrameworkSpawnerIdleTime 0

    # Just in case you're leaking memory, restart a listener 
    # after processing 5000 requests
    PassengerMaxRequests 5000


    # Only check for restart.txt et al up to once every 5 seconds, 
    # instead of once per processed request
    PassengerStatThrottleRate 5

    # Specify the minimum number of instances passenger can keep
    # while cleaning idle instances
    PassengerMinInstances 3

    <Location /redmine>
        Options Indexes -ExecCGI FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        # AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        # mod_rails
        # PassengerUser redmine
        #RailsEnv edoceo_live
        RailsBaseURI /redmine

        # environment.rb
        # Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"    
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>

# Then after the virtualhost is loaded, send it a request
# to initialize the redmine installation
PassengerPreStart http://2222.us/redmine/
```

It should be working but its not? Can someone advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

God I'm stupid, I was using the wrong ip.....

Comment: i had that plus a closed port 3000 and then found that it was only available on localhost and required -b xx.xx.xx.xx with the IP ... but this lit the fire of "ip" and i used netstat -plnt to prove it was listening, which lead me to see it was listening on 127.0.0.1, so available via wget locally, but not off the server. from there it was just a couple more Duhs.

Comment: Funny how this cropped up after all these years, glad you got it figured out too

Answer (score 0):

You may have firewall issues here, or more likely you need to set up port forwarding on your router to forward traffic on port 80 to your linux box.

Comment: I've been using the wrong IP the entire time, I asked google for my ip, when I should have just run ifconfig and got what it told me.